# Why is Hawaii pronounced Ha-waii instead of Ha-wa-ii?

Tags: syllables

Just realized the Japanese word Kawaii is pronounced Ka-wa-ii (three syllables).

With that in mind those two last "i" in Hawaii look suspicious now. Shouldn't they be pronounced separate, making up a third syllable?

Otherwise, what's the purpose of the double "i"?

Comment: What research can you include in your question about the pronunciation of these words?  What leads you to you think Hawai'i is not pronounced with three syllables?

Comment: Related if not bearing an answer: [The pronunciation of 'Hawaii'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/133783/36710)

Comment: You do know that Hawai'i is Hawaiian not Japanese, and the two languages are unrelated? You might as well be asking why Mexican-Spanish mole isn't pronounced like English mole.

Comment: @livresque Not really research but, I mean, it's all over the news now with those big fires. If you turn on the TV, or radio, or streams, everyone pronounces it with two syllables only. But you are probably right; people who know probably pronounces it right.

Comment: @StuartF Actually there *is* a connection between Hawaiian and Japanese, in that the transliteration into roman letters uses most of the same forms.  You can read Hawaiian as if it's written in Revised Hepburn and it'll work almost perfectly.  The languages aren't related, but the way we write them down using English letters are *very* closely related.

Comment: @TheImpaler When Americans are speaking quickly, they tend to skip the glottal stop and sort of slur from the ai to the ee. I suppose it could sound like one long syllable, but it's just sloppy pronunciation.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: there's a difference between pronouncing Hawaii with one long syllable (which you could say is sloppy) and saying Ha-why (which is wrong), and I don't think this difference is hard to hear.

Comment: tbh, the Japanese pronunciation of the 'ii' at the end of Kawaii can be so subtle as to barely hear it for a western ear; like the 'u' at the ends of many words, it's often little more than a subtle stop. I've never knowingly heard a Hawaiian say Hawaii, so I've no direct comparison.

Comment: @PeterShor I would agree with that statement, but if the OP thinks they're hearing two syllables on TV newscasts, that's the only explanation I can think of

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: Then the OP can't hear the difference between the pronunciation with a long second syllable and the incorrect pronunciation *Ha-why*.

Comment: In the mid-atlantic AmE dialect, It's Huh WHY_ee.  I'm using the _ to indicate that the final ee  [i] is an off-glide from the second syllable.  Perhaps that final [i] is not distinctly audible as a third syllable to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, it isn't a double-I; there's an apostrophe in there (called an "okina") if it's written correctly, but that detail is often ignored by English writers, and the state name officially doesn't include the okina (but IIRC, more because it predates common use of the diacritic marks than as an intentional exclusion).

Hawai'i is properly pronounced as three syllables: ha-WAI-ee. The okina in Hawaiian represents a glottal stop between the ai diphthong and the lone i. (The vowels in Hawaiian are said pretty much identically as in Japanese.)

Americans usually pronounce the name that way. I've never heard anyone call it "ha-wye", as two syllables. (My grandfather insisted on calling it Hawaya, but that was an intentional and obnoxious joke.) It's possible that what you're hearing is that Americans tend to skip the glottal stop and sort of slur from the ai to the ee, especially when speaking quickly. I suppose it could sound like one long syllable, but it's really two, just with sloppy enunciation.

When it's used as a demonym, we tend to skip the third syllable, or merge it with the -an suffix, so it comes out as "ha-wai-an" -- but not because we think the place is called ha-wai. I've never heard anyone say "ha-wai-ee-an" or anything like that, but since it's sort of mashing up two different languages, there is no real rule about how it "should" be said.

The only common variation in pronunciation that I know of is "ha-VAI-ee", because the Hawaiian language does not recognize a difference between W and V and the sound varies between the two, much like the R and L in Japanese.

Comment: R, L and D in Japanese. Get someone to say Kirin three times, chances are you'll get three different middle letters to a Western ear. [Explained to me by a Japanese friend many years ago.]

Comment: I've always heard it as a sound halfway between R and L, myself -- it's the throat movement you'd use for an R, but the tongue is in the L position.

Comment: mhm, but if the tongue bounces very slightly, a western ear will perceive a D. I've tried it on a few of my friends [I worked for a Japanese company for a decade, lots of Japanese friends]. It's really true you can get all three in just three attempts.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helps.

Comment: Are you sure your grandfather's pronunciation was a joke? There's a dialect that puts a schwa on the end of  *Missoura, Miama, Cincinnata,* and *Hawaia*; my grandmother did this (although I don't think I ever heard her pronounce *Hawaii*). She could pronounce *happy* just fine, so it's an idiosyncrasy having something to do with place names.

Comment: He never did it to any other place-names that I'm aware of, and my mother tried to correct him, which only prompted him to say it more, so at the very least he was doing it knowingly, and knowing it would annoy people. (The joke was that it sounds almost the same as how he would have said "How are you?")